# How do I use a function with parameters as a handler when using on() in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, handler, jquery-events

```
$('#editor'+id).on("click dbclick mousedown mousemove mouseover mouseout mouseup keydown keypress keyup blur change focus select", {param1:id}, editor_change);

function editor_change(id){
...does stuff...;
}
```

This function is supposed to take each textarea element with the id "editor" + a unique id (e.g. "editor24") and add a handler that detects an edit in the textarea. The function it is calling `editor_change` takes one parameter "id" that I need to include in the handler. How do I include this parameter when creating the handler?

Comment: You could extract the id number from `this.id`. But why not use common classes instead? Then you can probably just target by index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there actually is a built in method to pass data in exactly that way, I'll post it as answer, as I assume that is what you're looking for, not how to extract a number from an elements ID :

```
$('#editor'+id).on("click ...more events", {param1:id}, editor_change);

function editor_change(event){
    var passed_id = event.data.param1;
    alert(passed_id);
}
```

As you see, the passed object is available as `event.data`, and that's how the data parameter works in jQuery.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/29cTM/)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a parameter for this. Just do in this way:

```
$('#editor'+id).on("click dbclick mousedown mousemove mouseover mouseout mouseup keydown keypress keyup blur change focus select", function editor_change(event){
var id = parseInt(this.id.replace(/[^\d]/g, ''), 10);
});
```

Doing so, you're extracting the number from the element id.

Comment: This is ok, but it can be simplified. `[^\d] == \D` for example. Or shorter `var id = +this.id.match(/\d+/)[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Providing `id` is within scope of the handler, and does not change after the handler is attached, then it need not be passed as a parameter.

Either of the following will work :

```
var id = ...;
function editor_change() {
    //id is available here
}
$('#editor'+id).on("click etc", {param1:id}, editor_change);
```

or

```
var id = ...;
$('#editor'+id).on("click etc", {param1:id}, function() {
    //id is available here
});
```

Other scenarios also exist, in which `id` will be in scope.

If `id` likely to change (eg, it is assigned within a loop) after the handler is attached, then :

```
var id = ...;
$('#editor'+id).on("click etc", {param1:id}, function() {
    return function editor_change() {
        //id is available here
    };
}(id));
```